# How to use continue and break keywords in golang templates?

Tags: go-templates

For example:

```
{{range .Users}}
    {{if .IsAdmin}}
        {{/* How to use "break" or "continue"? */}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

The documentation for "break" or "continue" in templates is not available in [golang.org](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template)

Comment: Confirmed for Go 1.18 (Q4 2021). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653735/6309)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not documented because they do not exist.

To make sure - check the tests for the `text/template` lexer: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/text/template/parse/lex_test.go

Comment: But how can I accomplish this is go? Is there other way?

Comment: You cannot simulate `break`, and you don't need `continue` as long as you have `{{if`. Golang templates are not suited to have too complicated logic.

Comment: Can you share an example on how can I skip or stop an iteration?

Comment: You cannot stop an iteration. But you can skip with a simple `{{if .IsAdmin}}`. What is inside the `{{if }}` would only be rendered if the condition is true.

Comment: Ok I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[Go101 does mention](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1396107632620888064) (May 2021, 4+ years later):

> Since Go 1.18, "break" and "continue" might be supported in range loops of Go templates.

Note: [Go 1.18](https://dev.golang.org/release#Go1.18) should be released in Q1 2022.

That would solve [issue 20531](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20531) text/template: add `break` and `continue` support.
And is currently implemented in [CL 321491](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/321491/): `html/template`, `text/template`: implement `break` and `continue` for `range` loops.

This is still a work in progress for now (Q1 2021)

Update Sept. 2021: [confirmed](https://twitter.com/GoHugoIO/status/1440933835332591619), with [commit d0dd26a](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/d0dd26a88c019d54f22463daae81e785f5867565)

> ### `html/template`, `text/template`: implement `break` and `continue` for `range` loops
>
> `break` and `continue` for range loops was accepted as a proposal in June 2017.
> It was implemented in [CL 66410](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/66410/) (Oct 2017)
> but then rolled back in [CL 92155](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/92155/) (Feb 2018) because `html/template` changes had not been implemented.
>
> This CL reimplements break and continue in `text/template` and then adds support for them in html/template as well.

Answer (score 4):

`break` and `continue` statements are part of `text/template` and `html/template` in Go 1.10 (in Beta at time of writing). From the [release notes](https://beta.golang.org/doc/go1.10):

> The new actions `{{break}}` and `{{continue}}` break out of the innermost
>   `{{range ...}}` loop, like the corresponding Go statements.

Prior releases of Go (Before 1.10) do *not* support `break` or `continue` statements.

Looking at the beta documentation you can see the new `itemContinue` and `itemBreak` items in the [lexer](https://beta.golang.org/src/text/template/parse/lex.go), the new nodes like `ContinueNode` in [Parser](https://beta.golang.org/src/text/template/parse/parse.go) to follow the code.

Comment: The new break and continue actions do not work in html/template, and
fixing them requires thinking about security issues that seem too
tricky at this stage of the release. We will try again for 1.11.
https://github.com/golang/go/commit/fd7331a821a6b79d5f2f82075c032ac459670d7d

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to add a in processing check and skip any existing checks for the remainder of the loop.

```
// method 1
{{ $dothing := false }}
{{ range $i, $A := .List }}
  {{ if $A.Check }}
    {{ $dothing = true }}
  {{end}}
{{ end }}
{{ if $dothing }}
  // do thing
{{ end }}

// method 2
{{ $already := false }}
{{ range $i, $A := .List }}
  {{ if $already }}
  {{ else }}
    {{ if $A.Check }}
      {{ $already = true }}
      // do thing
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```