# Iterate over only the first n items of an array in a Go template

Tags: for-loop, go, slice, go-templates

I have a vector with `n` elements. I'm using it to render items in a template. But I need to render only the 5 first elements. Please note that is possible to have less than 5 elements in vector, in this case will render all elements. Is there is a way to do it in template?

```
{{range .Categorias}}
    <li class="nav-item">
        {{.Nome}}
    </li>
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest would be to only pass 5 elements, so you don't need any logic in the template.

You can also do this in template, if you also store the index in the `{{range}}` action. Then you can use an `{{if}}` action to check the index, and only render the body of the `{{if}}` if the index is less than 5:

```
{{range $i, $e := .Categorias}}{{if lt $i 5}}
    <li class="nav-item">
        {{.Nome}}
    </li>
{{end}}{{end}}
```

Here's a simple example demonstrating it:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))
    numbers := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, numbers); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const src = `{{range $i, $e := .}}{{if lt $i 5}}{{.}} {{end}}{{end}}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yFUaH5eU-U)):

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

#### Go 1.10 template extension

Note that in [Go 1.10](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.10#html/template) there will be new `{{break}}` and `{{continue}}` actions which will provide an alternative, better solution for this.

It will look something like this:

```
{{range $i, $e := .Categorias}}
    <li class="nav-item">
        {{.Nome}}
    </li>
{{if eq $i 4}}{{break}}{{end}}{{end}}
```

This new `{{break}}` action will provide a superior solution as the above `{{range}}` action will only iterate over 5 elements at most (while the other solution without `{{break}}` has to iterate over all elements, just elements with index >=  5 are not rendered).

#### Go 1.13 template extension

[Go 1.13 adds the `slice` builtin template function](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.13#text/template) which provides an even nicer and more efficient solution. Slice the value you want to range over, so the `{{range}}` action only "gets" what you want to loop over:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))
    numbers := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, numbers); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const src = `{{range $i, $e := (slice . 0 5)}}{{.}} {{end}}`
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MmExX_Q0_mG)):

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: `break` and `continue` in `range`? Soon... (Q1 2022 if all goes well): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653735/6309

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the note, will add it to the answer once it arrives :)